# what's wrong with my keras.using theano backend

Tags: deep-learning, keras, theano

i am learning to use deeping learning to deal with physics problem.when i want to run my program by theano,there are some bad things happended.

~$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:48:08) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import theano

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "theano.py", line 1
    %!PS-Adobe-3.0
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

> > > import keras
> > >       Using Theano backend.
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/**init**.py", line 3, in 
> > >           from . import utils
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/**init**.py", line 6, in 
> > >           from . import conv_utils
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py", line 3, in 
> > >           from .. import backend as K
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/**init**.py", line 80, in 
> > >           from .theano_backend import *
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 3, in 
> > >           import theano
> > >         File "theano.py", line 1
> > >           %!PS-Adobe-3.0
> > >           ^
> > >       SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Seems your theano installation is completely broken, as the theano.py file contains what it seems to be postscript data and not python code. You should reinstall theano.

Comment: yeah,maybe i have to give up doing it.my teacher told me that i dont need care for theano.tsflow is enough to train my data.

Comment: of course,if u have good idea to solve this problem,just tell me,thank u very much.